# Why is the probability of drawing a certain element from a population of size $N$ be $1/N$ even though the sampling is done without replacement?

Tags: probability, sampling

## Related:

[Trying to understand the derivation of expectation of sample mean $E(\bar x)= \mu$ where $\mu$ is the mean of the population](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202604/trying-to-understand-the-derivation-of-expectation-of-sample-mean-e-bar-x-m?lq=1)

---

I've been trying to understand $\mathrm E(x_i)= \mu$ where $x_i$ is the element at the $i^{\textrm {th}}$ draw from a population of size $N$ for making a sample of size $n$ by **SRSWOR**.

I read between the lines of my book again; here is the excerpt:

> Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ represent a simple random sample from the population $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$. In SRSWR, the probability of selection of any particular member of the population at any drawing remains a constant $1/N$; because before any drawing the population contains all the $N$ members. It may be shown that **this result is also true in SRSWOR**, although *the population size varies at each stage of the selection*. Thus, the probability of obtaining the population member $X_k$(suppose) at the $i$-th drawing is a **constant** $1/N$ both in SRSWR and **SRSWOR**; i.e., $$\mathrm P(x_i= X_k)= \frac{1}{N}$$

While I'm sure of this for SRSWR, I'm not getting this for SRSWOR.

How can the probability of drawing a certain element from the population at a certain draw be $1/N$ for even the author says '*the population size varies at each stage of the selection*'?

If after each turn, the population size is not the same, hoe can still the probability of drawing certain element be $1/N$ when the sampling is done without replacement?

Can anyone please explain me the case for SRSWOR?

Comment: It is illustrative to note that $P(X_2 = x) = \sum_{y=1}^n p(X_2 = x | X_1 = y) p(X_1 = y)$ by the law of total probability.

Comment: @AdamO: Is the book saying right?

Comment: Yes it is true that $P(x_i = X_k) = 1/N$, mathematically you would use induction to prove the general case. However, the intuition is that, "It's equally likely that all the other previous draws could be anything else."

Comment: @AdamO: Suppose, you pick up $X_k$ at the first turn; now wouldn't it be wrong to say $\mathrm P(x_2= X_k)= 1/N\;?$ For you've not replaced the element before the second turn, isn't it?

Comment: Yes but if the previous draws do *not* select that element on the $i$-th turn, you are *more* likely to draw that element on the $i$-th turn than with SRSWR. Think about the $N$-th draw, the $N-1$ possible cumulative permutations of previous draws which do draw the $k$th element have probability $(N-1)/N$, but the 1 possible draw that does include the $k$-th element has 100% probability of doing so, leading to probability $1/N$ for a successful draw.

Comment: How could the answer be anything *other* than $1/N$?  If it were, then it would be some definite function of the $N$ objects whose different values would distinguish among those objects--but under the assumptions of randomness, all objects play equivalent roles in the sampling model.

Answer (score 2):

By way of induction and the total law of probability it holds that:

$$P(X_2 = k) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(X_2 = k | X_1 = i) P(X_1 = i)$$

and supposing it holds for any $j$ that $P(X_j = k) = 1/N$ then

$$P(X_{j+1} = k) = \sum_{i=1} ^ N P(X_{j+1} = k | X_j = i) P(X_j = i)$$.

I think the comments I've contributed on the post contribute more of the intuition behind this finding.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, because the poster asked about "How can the probability of drawing a certain element from the population at *a certain draw* be 1/N" in SRSWOR. This is not the same thing as the overall  probability of selecting an element, which is the probability of selection at at *some* draw, which is indeed 1/N.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_l^{\textrm {j}}$ denotes an event that a particular unit $X_j$ is not selected at the $l^{\textrm {th}}$ draw. The probability of selecting, say, $k^{\textrm {th}}$ unit at $i^{\textrm {th}}$ draw is: (taking $A_i^{\textrm {k}}$= $A_i$)

\begin{align}
P (x_i = X_k) &= P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 .... A_{i-1} \cap \overline{A_i})\\
              &= P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_1A_2).....P(\overline{A_i}|A_1A_2...A_{i-1}) \\
              &= (1-\frac{1}{N})(1-\frac{1}{N-1})...(1-\frac{1}{N-i+2})\frac{1}{N-i+1}\\
              &= (\frac{N-1}{N})(\frac{N-2}{N-1})...(\frac{N-i+1}{N-i+2})\frac{1}{N-i+1}\\
              &= \frac{1}{N}
\end{align}